# Problemas com aspas ao importar dados do Excel para o Banco (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho um arquivo excel com vários dados, o problema é que aparentemente há alguns dados com aspas duplas e ao upar esses dados, todas as colunas ficam desajustadas e consequentemente os dados são populadas em colunas erradas (diferentes).
Estou usando `DreamCoder` para "jogar" os dados no banco. 
Não vi nenhuma aspas duplas no meu arquivo Excel, mas percebi que elas começaram a aparecer no banco.

aparentemente as aspas que fizeram os dados serem populadas em lugares errados... vi no meu arquivo excel original e não notei nenhuma aspas nesses dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt! Poste parte do seu arquivo csv e como está a tabela que irá recebe-lo no  banco para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Coloca algumas linhas do seu excel e como foi gravado no seu banco.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe é interessante colocar mais informações para podermos ajudar

Comment: coloquei uma imagem

Comment: @Otto acho que você me citou por engano, não sou o autor da pergunta hehe

Comment: @DiegoFelipe pode ser kkkkk

Answer (score 1):

Com a planilha do Excel aberta, tente efetuar estes passos:

- Tente substituir todas as aspas duplas `""` por qualquer outro
  carácter como parenteses `()` ou Espaço,
- Substitua todos as aspas simples `''` por qualquer outro carácter
  como parenteses `()` ou Espaço,
- Verifique qual o delimitador de campo que você esta utilizando, no
  meu caso, prefiro utilizar o ponto e virgula `;`, assim, eu substituo todos os ponto e virgulas `;` por virgulas `,`,
- Não esqueça de selecionar o Conjunto de caracteres, se não souber muito as diferenças, utilize `UNICODE UTF-8`

Todo este processo eu faço pelo LibreOffice ou OpenOffice, pela facilidade no momento de salvar o arquivo `.csv`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]